# How to filter a queryset by a list of strings in Django?

Tags: django

I have three models which are related to each other. Now I want to query a set of `Poller` entries which is filtered by the `categories_selected` by the user that stores strings of `poller_category`.

```
# Models

class Category(models.Model):
"""
Holds all available Categories
"""

    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class UserCategoryFilter(models.Model):
"""
Holds Categories selected by user
"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories_selected = models.CharField(max_length=2000)


class Poller(models.Model):
"""
Holds Poller objects
"""

    poller_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    poller_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

```
# View

def render_random_poller(request):

    # Get user category filter if logged in
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        # Get the Users filter as a list of selections
        category_filter = UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('categories_selected', flat=True)

        print(category_filter)

        # Get a Category instance filtered by user selection of categories
        category_instance = Category.objects.filter(category__in=category_filter)

        print(category_instance) # returns an empty queryset !!

        # Apply user's selection to the poller query and take 100 latest pollers
        qs_poller = Poller.objects.filter(poller_category__category__in=category_instance).order_by('-created_on')[:100]


    else:
    
        [...]
```

```
# View that saves/updated the categories_selected

[...]

        # Form validation
        if filter_form.is_valid():

            # Check if user already has a filter instance
            instance_exists = UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user)

            # Get the cleaned data
            selection = filter_form.clean()

            # Transform into json format for better data storing in Model
            selection = json.dumps([c.category for c in selection['choices']])

            # If not create, else update
            if not instance_exists:
                filter_instance = UserCategoryFilter(user=request.user,
                                                     categories_selected=selection)
                filter_instance.save()
[...]
```

However, `print(category_instance)` returns an empty queryset, even though `print(category_filter)` returns `['category_foo']`. How to get the queryset of Categories to use it as a filter for the Poller queryset?

This approach also returns an empty queryset:

```
category_instance = Category.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(category__in=x) for x in category_filter)))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `categories_selected` is a `CharField` and not a `ManyToManyField` to the `Category` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hm no, actually not :-/

Comment: but what is `categories_selected`? A space-separated list of category names? Since it is plural, I assume that this is some sort of collection that can "contain" multiple category items?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem comma separated list of category names, like e.g. `["Environment", "Sports"]`

Comment: but is this list about *one* `UserCategoryFilter`, or does the `categories_selected` contains list (including the `[`, `]`, etc. characters)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is about one instance of UserCategoryFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I understand it correctly, the `categories_selected` is a Python list you converted to a string, and thus is a list literal.

We can parse these back to a list of objects with:

```
from ast import literal_eval

qs = UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user)

categories = [
    item
    for uc in qs.values_list('categories_selected', flat=True)
    for item in literal_eval(uc)
]

category_instance = Category.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
```

I would however advise to work with a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) to link accounts to categories, like:

```
class UserCategoryFilter(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories_selected = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

In that case you can easily filter with:

```
Category.objects.filter(usercategoryfilter__user=request.user)
```

Django can thus make JOINs over many-to-many relations to move work from the Django/Python layer to the database layer.